# Filtering text file data before importing to excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am new to VBA and this forum. I Apologize in advance for the long text, formatting errors and the general noobness in my post.

I have a .txt file stored on a shared drive, that has details about multiple products. This file has more than 1048576 rows of data, and hence cannot be imported directly to the excel sheet. I wish to filter the data before importing based on filed 5 value being the number 60 (filed 5 is labeled as 'GL').

After some research I was able to put together the below module. In the '.CommanText' Array when I am doing a 'select *' I get all rows. But when I try to add a where clause for filtering the data I get an error "Run-time error '1004:General ODBC error". When I click debug the below line gets highlighted

.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

```
Sub ReadTextFile()
 ActiveSheet.Range("A1:S1045876").ClearContents 'clearing existing contents

 With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:=Array(Array("ODBC;DefaultDir=\\ant.org.com\dept\Systems\ABC\Data;Driver={Microsoft Text Driver (*.txt; *.csv)};DriverId=27;FIL=text;MaxBufferSize=2048;MaxSc"), Array("anRows=8;PageTimeout=5;SafeTransactions=0;Threads=3;UserCommitSync=Yes;")), Destination:=Range("A2"))
 .CommandText = Array( _
"SELECT * " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM filename.txt DQ") 'DQ is an arbitrary alias
.Name = "Query from Text"
.FieldNames = False
.RowNumbers = False
.FillAdjacentFormulas = False
.PreserveFormatting = False
.RefreshOnFileOpen = False
.RefreshStyle = xlOverwriteCells
.SavePassword = False
.SaveData = True
.AdjustColumnWidth = False
.RefreshPeriod = 0
.PreserveColumnInfo = True
.BackgroundQuery = True
.Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

End With

'code for excel "text to column" function

End Sub
```

Request your help in adding the ability to filter the data from the text file before importing.

Comment: [edit] filed 5 is a typo. It is meant to be field 5

Comment: Please include the "where" clause you tried.

Comment: "SELECT * FROM filename.txt  where GL=60" should work

Comment: Hi Tim,
I tried the below where clause, but keep getting the error Run-time error '1004:General ODBC error. 
    .CommandText = Array( _
    "SELECT * " & Chr(13) & "" & Chr(10) & "FROM 
    IDQ_Report_ALL_GL_LEAF_DEFECT_MKT_44571.txt DQ WHERE 
    GL=60")

I have also tried 
F5=60
[i]GL[/i]=60
and using single quotes for the value i.e. GL='60'

Each time I get the error, when i click debug 
".Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False" gets highlighted